# Flutter PageView inside Scrollable widgets

Tags: flutter

in my application i have one pageview with some pages into that

as you see i miss more size of screen

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
    ),
    home: App(),
  ));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'test text',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: PageView(
                          reverse: true,
                          onPageChanged: (i) {},
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 12.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.indigo[400],
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('33333333333333')),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 12.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.indigo[400],
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('33333333333333')),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 12.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.indigo[400],
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('11111111111111')),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0), child: Text('33333333333333')),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can i put this pageview into scrollable widgets such as listview without any problem?

when i put it inside `listview` or `expandable` i get error

what i want to have?

> ScrollableWidget [ container, pageview [ page1(), page1(), page3() ] ]

Comment: @saed-nabil could you help me?

Comment: please, send a minimal working code that will produce the error

Comment: @SaedNabil my post updated with testable code, thanks

Comment: Each child of a page view is forced to be the same size as the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a different approach to this problem , instead of make every thing scrollable you only scroll the header when the keybord is visible

you need to use keyboard_visibility plugin.

please check this code

```
class FragmentProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  .......

  @override
  State<FragmentProfile> createState() => _FragmentPage();
}

class _FragmentPage extends State<FragmentProfile> {
 ....

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ....
  }
}

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  .....
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  ....

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    .....
    _scrollController = ScrollController();

    KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
      onChange: (bool visible) {
        if(visible){
          final offset = _scrollController.offset;
          print("current offset = ${offset}");
          _scrollController.animateTo(
              offset+50.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              curve: Curves.easeIn);
        }else{
          final offset = _scrollController.offset;
          print("current offset = ${offset}");
          _scrollController.animateTo(
              offset-50.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
              curve: Curves.easeIn);

        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

        body: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 130,
            child: NestedScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,

                headerSliverBuilder:(BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled){
                  return <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      title: Component1(),
                      ),
                      centerTitle: true,
                      bottom: _buildMenuBar(context),
                      //pinned: true,
                      floating: true,
                      forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                    )
                  ];
                } ,
                body: PageView(
                    controller: _pageController,
                    reverse: true,
                    onPageChanged: (i) {},
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 12.0),
                          child: BmiCalculator(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                        child: ....
                      ),
                      ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                        child: Directionality(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 12.0),
                            child: UserProfileForm(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildMenuBar(BuildContext context) {
    ....
  }


}
```

Comment: problem is not changing listview with column, that is i have some widgets in pages and parent should be into list view, or scrollview

Comment: that means implementation should be like with my code

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to use slivers, please ,check the edit

Comment: no, in pages i have more widgets and i dont like to use listview for part of each pages and i dont have any problem with this implementation, and i want to put all pages as pageview into single scrollview

Comment: No problem, you can modify my code, put whatever widgets in pages and I will try to fix it

Comment: my post updated with your code and what i want to have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195168/discussion-between-doldurma-and-saed-nabil).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've to put `listview` inside of `BmiCalculator`, `RiskCalculator` and `UserProfileForm`